# Camerax Take Picture image.planes always empty

Tags: android, android-camerax

I try to take an image for memory usage but imageProxy.planes[0].remaining() is always 0. So I can not get an bitmap from the result. Is this a bug or what am I doing wrong?

Here is how I bind my camera:

```
private fun bindPreview(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider) {
    val cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        .build()

    imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setCaptureMode((ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY))
        .setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
        .setTargetRotation(rotation)
        .build()

    imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        .setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
        .setTargetRotation(rotation)
        .build()

    imageAnalyzer?.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, ImageAnalysis.Analyzer { image ->
        viewModel.analyzeImage(image)
    })

    preview = Preview.Builder()
        .setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
        .setTargetRotation(rotation)
        .build()

    cameraProvider.unbindAll()

    try {
        camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            this as LifecycleOwner,
            cameraSelector,
            preview,
            imageCapture,
            imageAnalyzer
        )
        preview?.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.createSurfaceProvider(camera?.cameraInfo))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e, "Could not bind camera.")
    }
}
```

And here is the code how I try to capture the image:

```
imageCapture?.takePicture(cameraExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
        override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
            Log.d(
                "test",
                "image -> height: ${image.height} | width: ${image.width} | format: ${image.format}"
            )
            Log.d(
                "test",
                "image -> planes.size ${image.planes.size} | planes[0].buffer.remaining ${image.planes[0].buffer.remaining()}"
            )
            Log.d(
                "test",
                "image -> image.image?.planes.size ${image.image?.planes?.size} | image.image?.planes[0].buffer.remaining ${image.image!!.planes[0].buffer.remaining()}"
            )

            // some code here

            image.close()
        }

        override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
            super.onError(exception)
            Timber.e(exception.cause, "Could not capture image.")
        }
    })
}
```

The height and width of the captured image seems to be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not operate on `image.image!!`.
Try to rewind `ByteBuffer` then check `remaining()`
Try:

```
val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer
buffer.rewind()
```

Comment: Hi, image.image!! was just for testing purpose.

buffer.rewind() did the trick! Thank you very much.